# Font size change without javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a below code where I am trying to increase or decrease the font size of text. If JavaScript is disabled in my browser, I am not able to increase or decrease the size of the text. Is there any way to do without JavaScript as my browser does use JavaScript for security reasons. Any suggestions will be really helpful.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/nwbmpdw4/1/)

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
   .Small{ font: 12px Times New Roman, Arial, Sans-Serif; }
   .Medium{ font: 15px Times New Roman, Arial, Sans-Serif; }
   .Large{ font: 18px Times New Roman, Arial, Sans-Serif; }
</style>

<script language="JavaScript">
   function changeFont(styleSheet)
   {
      document.getElementById('textArea').className=styleSheet;
   }   
</script>   
<noscript>Your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
</head>

<body>

   <span class="Small" id="textArea">Test which will change size</span>

   <br><br><br>

   <a href="javascript: changeFont('Small');">Small</a> &nbsp; 
   <a href="javascript: changeFont('Medium');">Medium</a> &nbsp; 
   <a href="javascript: changeFont('Large');">Large</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give reason for downvote.. or at least post a solution if answer already exists

Comment: Are there browsers without javascript in 2017?

Comment: Have multiple instances of page with different css. (hard to maintain), or if its php/.net ..  you could change css before delivery to client. (<a href=index.php?size=large ...)

Comment: @MarcoSalerno — https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/everyonehasjs.html

Comment: @Quentin yes but it still doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

I think someone mentioned about this, Javascript should be runnable for most of the cases so don't worry about it, although CSS hack is fun but sometimes not really useful in terms of readability, reliability and compatibility.

```css
html, body { font-family: "Arial"; }
.content { font-size: 10px; }
.small:checked ~ .content { font-size: 10px; }
.medium:checked ~ .content { font-size: 20px; }
.large:checked ~ .content { font-size: 30px; }
```

```html
<input class="small" name="font-radio" type="radio" checked="checked"/>
<input class="medium" name="font-radio" type="radio"/>
<input class="large" name="font-radio" type="radio"/>
<div class="content">I can change fontsize without Javascript!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no good ways.

You could do a really horrible hack involving checkboxes, [the `:checked` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked), the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) and some non-semantic markup … which would also massively constrain your design options.

Browsers come with built-in tools for adjusting the size of content. Focus on creating a fluid, responsive design instead. Let sizing issues be handled with the built-in zooming features of the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

As a general statement, once the page has been rendered and DOM was built, you can't change it without JavaScript. That's what JavaScript is supposed to do and that's what you are supposed to use.

As another general statement, *"my browser does not use JavaScript for security reasons"*, in most cases, simply shows lack of proper understanding of how web works today and, for the most part, it is plain wrong.
In other words, *today, no pages, including payment portals, do not disable JavaScript and, when properly coded, **JavaScript is safe***.

However, you could do this using CSS by, for example, (un)checking/selecting hidden checkboxes/radio buttons and having elements styled differently after a `:checked` or `:not(:checked)` element.

Here's a simple example:

```css
.content {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

#font-size-medium:checked ~ .content {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

#font-size-large:checked ~ .content {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
}

/* the rest is just styling, can be ignored for the purpose of the exercise */

#font-size-small:checked ~ [for="font-size-small"],
#font-size-medium:checked ~ [for="font-size-medium"],
#font-size-large:checked ~ [for="font-size-large"] { 
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  color: black;
}

[for^="font-size"] {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 .5rem 1rem 0; 
  cursor:pointer;
  color: #999;
}
[for^="font-size"]:hover {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
[name="font-size-change"] {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="font-size-small" name="font-size-change" checked>
<input type="radio" id="font-size-medium" name="font-size-change">
<input type="radio" id="font-size-large" name="font-size-change">
<label for="font-size-small">Small</label>
<label for="font-size-medium">Medium</label>
<label for="font-size-large">Large</label>
<div class="content">

  Put the text you want changed here...
  
</div>
```

But please note this change in rendering happens without changing anything in DOM. The elements remain the same, you're only changing what CSS rules apply to them, by (un)checking `<input>`s.